# install MSSQL inside a other Dockerfile

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, docker

it is possible to install MSSQL inside a php:7.3-apache Container?
it will be didn't happen at me...

and yeah it must ne MSSQL not mysql :D

FROM php:7.2-apache
here install MSSQL

Comment: You almost always run services like databases in separate containers.

Comment: I suggest you to post your question at [server vault](https://serverfault.com/), its not a development question